# Binomial probability question- A manufacturing firm knows that 4% of the products they produce are defective

Tags: probability

A manufacturing firm knows that 4% of the products they produce are defective. They accidentally shipped a
batch of 30 that had not been tested. If the receiving company randomly selects 7 of the 30 to be tested, what is
the probability none are defective?

I tried using the binomial formula: (30 choose 7)*(.96^7)*(.04^23), but the answer seems way too small to make sense. I don't know how I would use this formula or if there is a different way to solve it

Comment: What do you think? Consider how this relates to the material you studied, and edit the question to show the best effort you can make to solve the problem, explaining what you did and why. Without that effort, few people will be motivated to give a useful answer. In order to write the formulas you will surely need to write, look for help via this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I tried using the binomial formula: (30 choose 7)*(.96^7)*(.04^23), but the answer seems way too small to make sense.  I don't know how I would use this formula or if there is a different way to solve it

Comment: Can you give me any hints? i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The formula 
$$ {30 \choose 7}(0.96)^7(0.04)^{23} $$
is the probability that the shipment of $30$ parts contained exactly $7$ good parts.

There are at least two ways to attack a problem like this. One is very tedious to set up and involves huge amounts of calculation; the other is easy to set up and requires just a few calculations.

The hard way starts by computing the probability for each possible number of defective parts in the box. You have written the formula for $23$ defective parts; there are $30$ more formulas like it. 
For each possible number of defective parts, you multiply the probability of getting a box with that many defects times the probability that (given that box), if you draw $7$ parts from the box at random, you’ll get at least one of the defective ones. 
Then you add up all these probabilities.

The easy way is to consider the process by which the customer selected the $7$ parts to test, and ask why the probability of the outcomes of that process would differ from a process in which we take $7$ parts randomly from a box of $100$ untested parts, or even one where we simply take the first $7$ parts from that day’s production. Assuming any two parts have independent probabilities to be defective, the first part has a $0.04$ chance to be defective, the second part has a $0.04$ chance to be defective, and so forth, whether “first” means first off the production line that day or first tested among the $7$ parts taken from the box.

You may need to think about this further, but when you understand how this process works, you should be able to see that you can solve the problem without using the number $30$ anywhere in your calculations.